# MongoDB Range Issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, range

I'm using nodejs and mongodb.
I want to search docs between a num range but the function always give me number that outside the range. For example, this is my function and I want to get the results of the docs that they has a field size with the numbers between 1 to 1200:

```
db.collection(example).find({
  size: {
    "$gte": 1,
    "$lte": 1200
  }
}).toArray(function(err, results) {
  db.close();
  console.log("results=" + results);
});
```

the doc in the Database:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56659a492b9eaad2d9e6d4d2"), "size" : -1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56659a492b9eaad2d9e6d4d3"), "size" : 100 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56659a492b9eaad2d9e6d4d4"), "size" : 800 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56659a492b9eaad2d9e6d4d5"), "size" : 1999 }
```

the result of the query should be:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56659a492b9eaad2d9e6d4d3"), "size" : 100 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56659a492b9eaad2d9e6d4d4"), "size" : 800 }
```

but the query result is:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56659a492b9eaad2d9e6d4d2"), "size" : -1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56659a492b9eaad2d9e6d4d3"), "size" : 100 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56659a492b9eaad2d9e6d4d4"), "size" : 800 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56659a492b9eaad2d9e6d4d5"), "size" : 1999 }
```

Comment: I edited as you wanted

Comment: You've got duplicate `_id` values in your sample docs, but after fixing that it works fine when I try your query.

Comment: Is that the actual data? The Ids are duplicated

Comment: my bad... I copied it wrong, now it's true

Comment: Shouldn't the query be `$and: [ {$gte: 1}, {$lte: 1200} ]`?

Comment: the string that returned is :`MongoError: unknown operator: $and ` and I wrote this: `size: {
                                        $and: [
                                            {$gte: 1},
                                            {$lte: 1200}
                                            ]
                                    }`

Comment: Your query is correct and so is your data now. I believe the problem is somewhere else. Can you create a separate collection and add the data that you've provided and run the query from shell ?

Comment: you right... the problam was that my range properties was string and not int (in my project I wrote the 1 and the 1200 with ""). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to use a $and clause on your size conditions. It might look something like this:

```
db.collection(example).find( {
  $and: [
    { size: { $gte: 1 } }, 
    { size: { $lte: 1200 } } 
  ] } ).toarray...
```

See the examples in the mongo docs [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/#op._S_and).

**Edit:** Actually, an implicit and was fine. As noted, the actual problem here was size values were stored as strings, not ints.

Comment: @RandomGuy17 You don't need to use `$and`, so it's going to be misleading to future users to mark this accepted when the problem was actually that the `size` values in your docs were strings.